# Python requests library doesn't have all headers

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am using [python requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for a POST request and I expect a return message with an empty payload. I am interested in the headers of the returned message, specifically the 'Location' attribute. I tried the following code:

```
response=requests.request(method='POST', url=url, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'}, data=data)
print response.headers ##Displays a case-insensitve map
print response.headers['Location'] ##blows up
```

Strangely the 'Location' attribute is missing in the headers map. If I try the same POST request on [postman](http://www.getpostman.com/), I do get a valid Location attribute. Has anyone else seen this? Is this a bug in the requests library?

Comment: I think requests follows redirection, so it actually goes to that location IIRC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like everything's working as expected? Check your response.history

From the [Requests documentation](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/):

```
Requests will automatically perform location redirection for all verbs except HEAD.

>>> r = requests.get('http://github.com')
>>> r.url
'https://github.com/'
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

From the [HTTP Location page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location):

The HTTP Location header field is returned in responses from an HTTP server under two circumstances:

- To ask a web browser to load a different web page. In this circumstance, the Location header should be sent with an HTTP status code of 3xx. It is passed as part of the response by a web server when the requested URI has:

  - Moved temporarily, or
  - Moved permanently
- To provide information about the location of a newly-created resource. In this circumstance, the Location header should be sent with an HTTP status code of 201 or 202.[1](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

Comment: Thanks.  Setting allow_redirects to False did it. I should have looked into the documentation more thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

The requests library follows redirections automatically.

To take a look at the redirections, look at the history of the requests. [More details](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) in the docs.

Or you pass the extra allow_redirects=False parameter when making the request.